How to solve Perl's `length 'für' == 4` for `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`?
Implementing a line wrapping algorithm I realized that Perl's length function returns unexpected results if the input uses umlauts, like this (so the three-character string "für" has a length of four):
> perl -e 'print length "für" == 4, "\n"'
1

In detail (in Perl debugger):
  DB<7> x length "für"
0  4
  DB<8> foreach (0..3)  { print substr('für', $_), "\n" }
für
ür
▒r
r

  DB<9> q

The obvious question is:
How can I make Perl to interpret the string as UTF-8 string?
The manual suggests it should automatically.
"perluniintro(1)" states in " Perl's Unicode Model":

Perl supports both pre-5.6 strings of eight-bit native bytes, and
strings of Unicode characters.  The general principle is that Perl
tries to keep its data as eight-bit bytes for as long as possible, but
as soon as Unicodeness cannot be avoided, the data is transparently
upgraded to Unicode.  Prior to Perl v5.14.0, the upgrade was not
completely transparent (see "The "Unicode Bug"" in perlunicode), and
for backwards compatibility, full transparency is not gained unless
"use feature 'unicode_strings'" (see feature) or "use 5.012" (or
higher) is selected.

The code where I found the issue explicitly uses require 5.018_000;, so shouldn't Perl "do the right thing" automatically?
(I found an older question of mine (printf aligning problem with degree (°) character) with a similar problem, but connected to printing strings. I don't see how the answers apply here)
The Bytes
As I had been asked for the bytes in the string, here is what I got:
> perl -e "print 'für'" | od -x
0000000 c366 72bc
0000004
> perl -e "print unpack('H*', 'für');" -e 'print "\n"'
66c3bc72
> perl -e "print 'für'" | hexdump -C
00000000  66 c3 bc 72                                       |f..r|
00000004

use utf8 as a Solution
It had been suggested to use utf8, and actually I had been trying it, but it doesn't really work, and I don't understand either:
> perl -de1

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> use utf8

  DB<2> print length "für"
4
  DB<3> q
> perl -Mutf8 -de1

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> print length "für"
4
  DB<2> q
> perl -Mutf8 -de 'print length "für", "\n"'

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   print length "für", "\n"
  DB<1> n
3
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
  DB<1> q
>

use Encode as a Solution
The solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/78821233/6607497 works, but I wonder why I need to explain that the string is UTF-8 to perl:
  DB<1> use Encode qw(decode)

  DB<2> $x='für'

  DB<3> $y = decode('UTF-8', $x)

  DB<4> x length $x
0  4
  DB<5> x length $y
0  3


If I use (the deprecated) use encoding ':locale', then the length for für is reported as 3.

Related: an answer to "How can I determine how many columns a string will occupy when printed to the console?"

If the utf8 string is appearing as a string literal within the source, then you need to tell perl that the source file is utf8-encoded, with
use utf8;

If the string comes from another source, such as from a file or on the command line, then you need to tell perl that the file or command line is utf8-encoded, for example:
open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename;

and
perl -CSA script utf8-arg ...

For example,
$ printf '\x66\xc3\xbc\x72' |
perl -Mv5.14 -CSA -nle'say length'
3

$ printf '\x66\xc3\xbc\x72' |
perl -Mv5.14 -nle'use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)"; say length'
3


The OP seems to know how to use UTF-8; I don't see how this attempts to answer their question.

Actually before asking the question I did try use utf8, and it made no difference.

Strange; with en_US.UTF-8 and adding -Mutf8 to your one-liner does the trick for me with v5.38.

Same here. perl -Mutf8 -E 'say length "für"' prints 3 for me. Where does your "für" actually come from?

It's very interesting: When I use utf8 in a debugger session, then the test fails, but if I specify -Mutf8 on the command line, then it succeeds. See edited question in a moment.

@user20284150 "für" comes from the keyboard (via Windows remote desktop and PuTTY (sorry that's the company policy).

You can use Unicode::Normalize to force accented characters to their shortest possible representation; but ultimately, the display width of a Unicode sequence is not predictable just from the length of its Unicode representation; and there are many, many accented characters which do not have a single-glyph representation.
To somewhat unpack this, ü can be represented as either the single glyph U+00FC or as the composed sequence U+0075 LATIN SMALL LETTER U followed by U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS.
tripleee$ perl -CSD -le 'print(length($_), " ", $_)
>   for ("fu\x{0308}r", "f\x{00fc}r")'
4 für
3 für

tripleee$ perl -MUnicode::Normalize -CSD -le '
    print(length(NFC("fu\x{0308}r")))'
3

But for example m̈ has no precomposed form, and will always have a length($_) of 2.
On a Mac, for example, the decomposed form is preferred, and what you will typically end up with if you copy/paste this string.
If you need to establish the display width of an arbitrary string, you'll realistically need to find a library which calculates it for you.
How to know the preferred display width (in columns) of Unicode characters? seems relevant, but pretty old, and not about Perl.
However, that led me to this question on Unix.SE which (indirectly) suggests Text::CharWidth.
tripleee$ perl -MText::CharWidth=mbswidth -le 'print(mbswidth("fu\x{0308}r"))'
3

There is also Unicode::CharWidth.

With use Unicode::Normalize I'm still getting length 4 for x length 'für' in the Perl debugger.

Normalized to what? What are the actual bytes in your input string?

You need to do more than just use Unicode::Normalize;. You actually need to normalize your unicode strings. See the documentation of Unicode::Normalize for how to do this, and which normalization you want.

I updated the answer to show how to use NFC() for normalization and Text::CharWidth::mbswidth()

The Unicode::GCString module (Part of Unicode::LineBreak) treats multi-codepoint extended grapheme clusters like u + U+0308 as a single character for the purposes of string operations:
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.36;
use utf8;
use open ':std', IO => ':locale';
use Unicode::GCString;

my $s = Unicode::GCString->new("f\N{U+00FC}r");
say "$s length: ", $s->length; # 3
my $s2 = Unicode::GCString->new("fu\N{U+0308}r");
say "$s2 length: ", $s2->length; # also 3
my $s3 = Unicode::GCString->new("für"); # Could be normalized to either form
say "$s3 length: ", $s3->length; # also 3

However in your specific case the issue is how perl is treating the argument to -e as raw bytes, not a unicode string.
$ perl -E 'say length "für"'
4
$ perl -Mutf8 -E 'say length "für"'
3

The above assumes the f\N{U+00FC}r version, encoded into UTF-8 as the bytes 66 c3 bc 72). The A argument to the -C option doesn't seem to apply to the argument to -e or -E; it needs -Mutf8 to tell perl the string to execute is UTF-8 encoded:
$ perl -CSA -E 'say "für"' # mojibake output
fÃ¼r
$ perl -CS -Mutf8 -E 'say "für"'
für

(The documentation does say -CA applies to @ARGV strings, and options processed by perl itself aren't in @ARGV, so it's not wrong, but is confusing)

This is the way. When you start thinking at this level, you have to be very careful to think about what you want because the term "character" is too imprecise in common parlance. There's how many octets it takes to store (or takes up in a message), how many boxes it takes up in a UI component, and so on. The later editions of Learning Perl has a Unicode primer for just this reason.

You need to tell perl that something is text in order to have it interpreted correctly.
So if you know that some scalar $var contains octets of a UTF-8 encoded string that you received from somewhere outside your program code you may do:
use Encode qw(decode);
say length decode('UTF-8', $var);


Actually it works, but why do I need it at all?
